Using multiple client certificates with Python and Selenium
I’m working on a web-scrape project using Python and Selenium with a Chrome driver, which requires client certificates to access pages.  I have 2 scenarios it must handle:

Different certificates allow access to different URLs (e.g. Certificate A accesses URLs 1, 2 and 3, and Certificate B accesses URLs 4, 5 and 6)
Multiple certificates can access the same URL (e.g. Certificate A and B both can access URLs 7, 8 and 9 – those URLs return different company-specific data with each different cert)

I’m on Windows/Windows Server, and have used the Registry entry AutoSelectCertificateForUrls, which auto-selects a certificate, based on URL (or wildcard).  But for scenario #2 above, it does no good.
So ideally, I’d like to pass the URL and Cert name to the Python script, then have Chrome use that Cert when accessing the specified URL, but I’m not seeing a way to do that.  So far, I have:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 

driver.get(url)
:
:
# scrape code here

Does anyone have good step-by-step instructions to handle this?

import sqlite3
import win32crypt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DATABASE_PATH = 'path/to/database.db'  # Database with URLs and cert thumbprints
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'path/to/chromedriver'

def fetch_thumbprint_for_url(url):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT thumbprint FROM certs WHERE url = ?", (url,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return result[0] if result else None

def get_cert_from_store(thumbprint):
    store = win32crypt.CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER
    store_handle = win32crypt.CertOpenStore(win32crypt.CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, None, store, "MY")
    cert_context = win32crypt.CertFindCertificateInStore(
        store_handle,
        win32crypt.X509_ASN_ENCODING,
        0,
        win32crypt.CERT_FIND_HASH,
        thumbprint,
        None
    )
    if cert_context:
        return cert_context[0].get("CERT_CONTEXT")
    raise Exception("Certificate not found.")

def setup_driver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    service = Service(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
    return webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

def access_url_with_cert(url):
    thumbprint = fetch_thumbprint_for_url(url)
    if not thumbprint:
        raise Exception("No thumbprint found for this URL.")
    cert = get_cert_from_store(thumbprint)
    if not cert:
        raise Exception("Certificate retrieval failed.")
    driver = setup_driver()
    driver.get(url)
    return driver

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_url = "https://example.com"  # Update with the actual URL
    driver = access_url_with_cert(test_url)
    driver.quit()


I cannot get this to work.  I always get "Access to xyz.com was denied."  I've tried as you suggest with the pfx and password (which works fine btw, when I import the pfx into the Windows certificate store and go to xyz.com directly in Chrome).  I've also tried different formats of the Path - e.g. C:\certs\mycert.pfx and C:/certs/mycert.pfx.  I have also tried both --client-certificate-file and --ssl-client-certificate-file.  The only way I can get it to work is to import the cert into my personal certificate store in Windows (as the only certificate), then I gain access.  Suggestions?

How about  try importing it into the Windows Certificate Store programmatically or manually, and then running Chrome without the file path
or use  win32crypt Library for importing the certificate to the personal store before running the script.
N.B: i have modified the script to use  win32crypt Library for importing the certificate to the personal store before running the script.

Yes, I have imported certs into the Windows store manually.  So, let's say I have Cert A, B, and C imported.  For URL1, I wish to use Cert A, for URL2 and URL3, I wish to use Cert B, and for URL4, I wish to use Cert C.  I'd like to keep the URL and Cert ID (e.g. thumbprint) in a database, then depending on the URL I'm visiting, pull the correct cert ID, grab it from the Windows store, and use it when I instantiate the driver.  How can I accomplish that?

Store the URL and thumbprint for each certificate in a database table.
Use pywin32 to access the Windows Certificate Store by thumbprint.
Use the certificate directly when instantiating the Chrome driver.
i already modified the code again it should help you. you can refactor further

Your answer seems appropriate; though my default cert (the one I've imported to the Windows store last), is always used, instead of the one whose thumbprint I specify.  I'll accept your answer for now, and will post any new revelations if they come up.
